# PID Autotune not working and M92 calibration not saving?

Tags: marlin, pid

I have a Witbox 2 running Marlin that I got second hand and it seems like nothing is able to be calibrated on it. I have tried many times to get the nozzle calibration to save but it never seems to save my values, even with the `M500` command.

Also, when I try to run PID autotune the temperature just stops reading (only reads 0 °C) and then gives me a timeout error and disconnects me from the printer.

I am new to 3D printers and have no clue what is happening here. The printer prints almost perfectly. I just want to hone it a bit more to make it as good as possible, but it seems like it's not an option for some reason. Can someone offer an idea as to what is happening? Did I get a bad printer?

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! To be sure, what do you mean by "nozzle calibration"?

Comment: What firmware version do you use? Did you compile it yourself? Is EEPROM enabled?